# Connection to SQL server Fails after system hibernate

Tags: sql-server, windows, delphi, ado

I am using ADOConnection component in delphi to connect to SQL. once the system wakes up after system(windows 10) hibernate ,the connection to the SQL is lost.

But Call to close and reopen the connection works.

Would like to get some idea from this forum why this is happening during hibernation???

Comment: Well, if the Sql Server is expecting some kind of periodic "keep alive" signal from the client (or vice versa), when the client goes into hibernation, this will not be sent/received, which would make it appear that the client has "gone away".

Comment: This is usually the case. Nearly all SQL-Servery expect a "keep alive" to keep the connection open after a set timeout period is over. Otherwise the server will close the connection to prevent unnecessary high connection numbers with dormant clients. If you want to keep the connection open, you will need to alter the settings of your SQL server to never close connections by its own, which is something i would not recommend at all. I would strongly suggest you try to implement a check if the connection is still valid before trying to use it again and then reconnect if it isn't open anymore.